# Checking for membership of "top" value using OGNL in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

I am using Struts 2 with JSP templates and the Struts 2 tags. With these, I can't seem to check for membership of a value in a `HashMap`.

The map is set up correctly, there is a `List<Taxon>` I'm iterating over, and I would like to check if the element exists in a map I have, called `synonyms` which is of type `Map<Taxon, Taxon>`.

When I check with the `in` operator, I always get false, i.e.:

```
<s:if test="top in synonyms"> .... </s:if>
```

On the other hand, this is always true:

```
<s:if test="synonyms[top] != null"> ... </s:if>
```

If I do the following, I get the correct value if the element is in the map, and some sort of null value if it is not:

```
<s:property value="synonyms[top].name />
```

The weird thing is, if `taxon` is a property of whatever I'm iterating (i.e. I wrap it in another class), then the checking if the `element != null` actually works fine. Is this a bug in OGNL or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just checking but top _is_ the top of the value stack right? Can't see the variable names so I hope there isn't a parameter called top, that would be really confusing. I would find it easier to read if you specified "top in synonyms.values" or "top in synonyms.keys" ... if all else fails write your own public method to perform the test (it would probably be more efficient)

Comment: Yes, top of the value stack.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the element of one collection which you are iterating contains in another collection usually use `contains` method. To call it via OGNL use

```
<s:if test="synoynms.values.contains(top)">
```

or

```
<s:if test="synoynms.keys.contains(top)">
```

it will use Java to determine belonging the `top` element in the `iterator` tag to the collection.

Comment: I'll try this, but the docs do state that testing with "in" should work: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ognl.html

Comment: When I try `synonyms.keys.contains(top)`, it always returns true. Just as if I do `synonyms[top] != null`.

Comment: @wds The doc uses simple lists even created by OGNL *in* which it's able to do comparisons, other collections may not work, so use Java to determine belonging object to the collection.

Comment: what you suggest doesn't work either, it does work when using any other element but the `top' pointer, but not with that one.

Comment: It works fine, using the code above, I don't know what are you trying may not work, because you doing something wrong.

Comment: The answer did not help me (7 years ago) so I cannot mark it as accepted.